# Can't save file with .json extension

Tags: java, android, json, file

when I am trying to save my file as .txt or .xml the file created on my device but when I am trying to save it as .json the file never created.
This is how I call my method

```
  String test = "test";
  String fileName = "kyriakos.txt";
  saveDataToFile(AnswerQ1, fileName);

public void saveDataToFile(String answer, String fileName) {

   Log.d("Checks", "Trying to save data");

   try {
        // Set up the file directory
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Data Folder";
        File fileDirectory = new File(filePath);
        fileDirectory.mkdirs();
        Log.d("Checks", "Directory created");

       // Set up the file itself
        File textFile = new File(fileDirectory, fileName);
        textFile.createNewFile();
        Log.d("Checks", "File created");

       // Write to the file
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(textFile,true);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
        outputStreamWriter.append("  " +"\"fcov\":" +"  "+ "\""+answer+"\","  +  "\n" );
        outputStreamWriter.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done writing to SD card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }}
```

Comment: No errors? No StackTrace?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your json in ShredPreference as a string

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my device didn't recognise json files so I download a file explorer app and I found my json file